# Spring Boot and Apache Shiro - No mappings can be found after Shiro is configured

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, shiro

I have a problem with controller mappings in Spring Boot.
After I added the Spring-JPA dependency, none of my mappings work anymore.

- Deleting the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency helps but usage of JPA is intendend
- The controller class is located in a subpackage under the class containing the main method
- The Application starts and throws no exceptions. Connection to the database is also working

Mappings when JPA dependency is added:

```
2018-03-25 16:02:14.550  INFO 1820 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-03-25 16:02:14.551  INFO 1820 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
```

Mappings after JPA dependency is removed (how it's expected to be):

```
2018-03-25 16:28:35.907  INFO 1032 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/ || /index],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.aggrogator.controller.frontend.HomeController.getHome(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2018-03-25 16:28:35.909  INFO 1032 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET || POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.aggrogator.controller.frontend.HomeController.postLogin(com.aggrogator.model.Login)
2018-03-25 16:28:35.920  INFO 1032 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-03-25 16:28:35.921  INFO 1032 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Aggrogator</artifactId>
    <version>${version.number}</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Aggrogator</name>
    <description>News-Aggregator</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <version.number>${git.commit.id.abbrev}</version.number>
        <master.branch>latest</master.branch>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-spring-boot-web-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0-RC2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Shiro uses SLF4J for logging.  We'll use the 'simple' binding
             in this example app.  See http://www.slf4j.org for more info. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.theborakompanioni</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-shiro</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <!--Import other Plugins for feature-branches or master-branch-->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                        <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                    <goal>push</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <repository>damian.space:81/aggrogator/aggrogator</repository>
                            <tag>${version.number}</tag>
                            <buildArgs>
                                <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                            </buildArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>master</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                        <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                    <goal>push</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <repository>damian.space:81/aggrogator/aggrogator</repository>
                            <tag>latest</tag>
                            <buildArgs>
                                <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                            </buildArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <dateFormat>yyyyMMdd-HHmmss</dateFormat><!--  human-readable part of the version number -->
                    <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFile>false</generateGitPropertiesFile><!-- somehow necessary. otherwise the variables are not available in the pom -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Application:

```
package com.aggrogator;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AggrogatorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AggrogatorApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
package com.aggrogator.controller.frontend;

import com.aggrogator.model.Login;
import org.apache.shiro.authz.annotation.Logical;
import org.apache.shiro.authz.annotation.RequiresRoles;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    // Important for @ModelAttribute to work below!
    @ModelAttribute("login")
    public Login getLoginObject() {
        return new Login();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @RequiresRoles(logical = Logical.OR, value = {"admin","emperor"})
    public String getHome(Model model){

        return "index";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String postLogin(@ModelAttribute("login") Login login){

        return "login";
    }

}
```

Application.properties:

```
shiro.loginUrl = /login

# Let Shiro Manage the sessions
shiro.userNativeSessionManager = true

# disable URL session rewriting
shiro.sessionManager.sessionIdUrlRewritingEnabled = false

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aggrogator
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pw
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

**Update**

Found out some more information
If i add the dependency "shiro-spring" instead of "shiro-spring-boot-web-starter" the mappings get added, but following Exception is thrown on request:

```
org.apache.shiro.UnavailableSecurityManagerException: No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code, either bound to the org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static singleton.  This is an invalid application configuration.
```

This exception is clearly thrown because no SecurityManager was found while processing shiro tags in the html template. Removing the shiro tags this exception is not thrown anymore, but no security functions are working (all sites accessible).

After some fiddling I was able to reproduce the beforementioned issue by adding some Beans to the Shiro configuration (still using shiro-spring dependency). Also this is the minimum configuration that reproduces the issue of missing mappings:

```
package com.aggrogator.configuration;

import at.pollux.thymeleaf.shiro.dialect.ShiroDialect;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService;
import org.apache.shiro.cache.CacheManager;
import org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager;
import org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager;
import org.apache.shiro.realm.Realm;
import org.apache.shiro.realm.text.PropertiesRealm;
import org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor;
import org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor;
import org.apache.shiro.spring.web.config.DefaultShiroFilterChainDefinition;
import org.apache.shiro.spring.web.config.ShiroFilterChainDefinition;
import org.apache.shiro.spring.web.config.ShiroWebConfiguration;
import org.apache.shiro.spring.web.config.ShiroWebFilterConfiguration;
import org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;

@Configuration
public class ShiroConfig {

    @Bean
    public Realm realm() {
        // uses 'classpath:shiro-users.properties' by default
        PropertiesRealm realm = new PropertiesRealm();
        // Caching isn't needed in this example, but we can still turn it on
        realm.setCachingEnabled(true);
        return realm;
    }

    @Bean
    public ShiroFilterChainDefinition shiroFilterChainDefinition() {
        DefaultShiroFilterChainDefinition chainDefinition = new DefaultShiroFilterChainDefinition();
        // Paths that need to authenticate over the login page
        chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/**", "authc");
        // Path for logout. The session calling it wil be logged out
        chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/logout", "logout");
        // Paths that shouldn't require authentication like static resources.
        chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/css/**", "anon");
        chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/images/**", "anon");
        chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/js/**", "anon");
        chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/vendor/**", "anon");
        return chainDefinition;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        // Caching isn't needed in this example, but we will use the MemoryConstrainedCacheManager for this example.
        return new MemoryConstrainedCacheManager();
    }

    /**
     * Shiro Thymeleaf dialect like described at
     * https://github.com/theborakompanioni/thymeleaf-extras-shiro
     * and derived from
     * https://shiro.apache.org/web.html#jsp-gsp-tag-library
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public ShiroDialect shiroDialect() {
        return new ShiroDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultPasswordService defaultPasswordService(){
        return new DefaultPasswordService();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultSecurityManager securityManager(){
        DefaultSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultSecurityManager();
        securityManager.setRealm(realm());
        return securityManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor(){
        return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean(){
        MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
        methodInvokingFactoryBean.setStaticMethod("org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager");
        methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(new Object[]{securityManager()});
        return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn(value="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator(){
        return new DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor(){
        AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor = new AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor();
        authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor.setSecurityManager(securityManager());
        return authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor;
    }


}
```

Now it is clear to me that the Shiro configuration is responsible for this problem. I hope that someone here has a deeper understanding of Shiro and its Spring integration.

Comment: There's too much detail for others to digest before they can help you with your problem. You need to give more summary information about the symptoms, and what you've done to try to localize the source of the problem. Ideally, a minimal complete example program that reproduces the problem would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi, I've already tried to give minimal code. From my point of view everything that is given in my post is relevant. Or could you specify what you mean?

Comment: HTML Templates?  Are you using JSP tags or thymeleaf-extras-shiro ?

Comment: I use Thymeleaf-extras-shiro Templates.

Comment: what do you mean by "none of my mappings work anymore"?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem as you. In the end, after repeated debugging, I confirmed that as long as you use shiro-spring-boot-starter and spring-aspects at the same time, this happens: the controller that uses Shiro's annotations. All RequestMapping will disappear, see the log can confirm that it has not been scanned at all, I think this is a bug of shiro-spring-boot-starter 1.4.0, I later changed to JavaConfig, configure Shiro myself, there is no such phenomenon. Or you can get rid of spring-aspects. My English is very bad, I hope you can understand